# Gradle DSL method not found:'compileOptions()'

Tags: java, android, gradle, gradle-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.new"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 51
        versionName "2.0.5"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.org'
        }
    }
}


compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibsility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}



dependencies {
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'

}

################################################################################
Task.java

package bolts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Represents the result of an asynchronous operation.
 * 
 * @param <TResult>
 *          The type of the result of the task.
 */
public class Task<TResult> {
  /**
   * An {@link java.util.concurrent.Executor} that executes tasks in parallel.
   */
  public static final ExecutorService BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR = BoltsExecutors.background();

  /**
   * An {@link java.util.concurrent.Executor} that executes tasks in the current thread unless
   * the stack runs too deep, at which point it will delegate to {@link Task#BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR} in
   * order to trim the stack.
   */
  private static final Executor IMMEDIATE_EXECUTOR = BoltsExecutors.immediate();

  /**
   * An {@link java.util.concurrent.Executor} that executes tasks on the UI thread.
   */
  public static final Executor UI_THREAD_EXECUTOR = AndroidExecutors.uiThread();

  /**
   * Interface for handlers invoked when a failed {@code Task} is about to be
   * finalized, but the exception has not been consumed.
   *
   * <p>The handler will execute in the GC thread, so if the handler needs to do
   * anything time consuming or complex it is a good idea to fire off a {@code Task}
   * to handle the exception.
   *
   * @see #getUnobservedExceptionHandler
   * @see #setUnobservedExceptionHandler
   */
  public interface UnobservedExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * Method invoked when the given task has an unobserved exception.
     * <p>Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored.
     * @param t the task
     * @param e the exception
     */
    void unobservedException(Task<?> t, UnobservedTaskException e);
  }

  // null unless explicitly set
  private static volatile UnobservedExceptionHandler unobservedExceptionHandler;

  /**
   * Returns the handler invoked when a task has an unobserved
   * exception or {@code null}.
   */
  public static UnobservedExceptionHandler getUnobservedExceptionHandler() {
    return unobservedExceptionHandler;
```

Even after downloading the jdk 1.7 and installing it, I still have this error

Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileOptions()'
Possible causes: The project 'app' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
fixGradleElements>Fix plugin version and sync projectThe project 'app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
open.wrapper.file>Open Gradle wrapper file.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: Just one thing, although that is probably not the cause of your problem; you have a typo in `targetcompatib**s**ility` (note the extra 's')

Answer (score 4):

although you have a typo the real problem is that this:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Should be inside the android {} closure like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.new"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 51
        versionName "2.0.5"
    }

    //FIX
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.org'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Your problem will be raised by this property `targetCompatibsility`, must be `targetCompatibility`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

btw, are you sure that don´t need to define some dependencies inside your `build.gradle` file :

```
dependencies {

      ???
}
```

Comment: So, such a typo _can_ be a cause for a method not found? Uh. I'll have learned something today...